# $in operator titanium sdk not working #appcelerator

Tags: javascript, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-arrow

My code looks like this

```
Cloud.Events.query({
            where: {
            tags : {'$in': ['movie','netflix']}

        }   

        }, function (e) {//continues
```

and on the arrowdb backend I have pushed in values to make tags for the event look like `[" ","movie","netflix"]`. Its not picking up the event. I'm using Titanium SDK syntax.

Comment: Am I correct this does not get you any events while you do see events that have either/both "movie" and "netflix" as tag if you request a list of all events (by leaving out the where or using .show() with the id)?

Comment: I've filed it as a bug

Answer (score -1):

I also had some trouble with this in the past.

I solved it playing with syntax.

At the end, I reached a solution like:

```
var where = null

where.tags = {
    '$in': [your array]
};

Cloud.Events.query({
    where: where
}, function (e) {});
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: This results in the same payload